# A view component named 'PreviewCV' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have created a view component.

```
public class PreviewCVComponent : ViewComponent
{
 ..


    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I have added a folder into views/shared/components which is given the name PreviewCV. Under that folder I have added a view called Default.cshtml.

The Component is called from another view. Which is located under views/CV, and has the name CV.cshtml.

I am trying to call the component with the use of

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("PreviewCV", new { id = -1 })
```

This results in:

> InvalidOperationException: A view component named 'PreviewCV" could not be found. A view component must be a public non-abstract class, not contain any generic parameters, and either be decorated with 'ViewComponentAttribute' or have a class name ending with the 'ViewComponent' suffix. A view component must not be decorated with 'NonViewComponentAttribute'.

I am using .net core.

Comment: *either be decorated with 'ViewComponentAttribute' or have a class name ending with the 'ViewComponent' suffix.* - Which one of those does your class satisfy? Interestingly, the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2#creating-a-view-component) say simply deriving from `ViewComponent` is enough but the error message says otherwise.

Comment: hahaha... well. Thanks.

Comment: Tactful yet sassy

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to call it like:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync(typeof(PreviewCVComponent), new { id = -1 })
```

Answer (score 2):

**--In Models folder**

FileName: `TestViewComponent.cs`

**--In TestViewComponent class**

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "TestViewComponent")] //Solution
public class TestViewComponent: ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Put `ViewComponent` in suffix solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using **net core 5.0**, class name (e.g. PreviewCV) can either be written as `PreviewCV` OR `PreviewCVViewComponent`

so

```
public class PreviewCV : ViewComponent
```

and

```
public class PreviewCVViewComponent : ViewComponent
```

will work fine while below will generate error (same as shown in question)

```
public class PreviewCVComponent : ViewComponent
```

Also noticed that attribute didn't have any effect on these

```
[ViewComponentAttribute]
```